# Does Polars Implement Pandas Compatible Relational Functions?

Tags: relational, boolean-operations, python-polars

Looks like Polars doesn't implement the commonly used Pandas relational functions e.g `df['Qty'].ge(100)`, at least not at this time. I've warmed up to Pandas relational functions syntax especially since operator priority bugs become a non-issue, reduces parenthesis matching errors and provides more syntactic compatibility when porting code. Definitely not a deal breaker. Seems like a deliberate decision not to implement but what's the rationale?

Comment: They are requested more often. If you open an issue we can add them in a future release.

Comment: Done. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5992